# Glimpse Not Debugging Ajax or Pages With Web Controls

Tags: asp.net, ajax, debugging, user-controls, glimpse

I've used glimpse before, but it down and now I've come back. 
I like how i can see the SQL generated from EF!

However I have a few issues:

1. I cannot debug ajax request:

   - I've check to make sure the request has a Glimpse payload (Glimpse-Parent-RequestID)
   - I've edited my web config to add content types for JSON and XML
2. Glimpse seems to have issues with pages that use a custom web user control

   - My local IIS (process w3wp.exe) throws a stackoverflow exception
   - the error goes away when I turn Glimpse off.
   - the Glimpse.log trace file doesn't show any issues

I'm using the latest version of Glimpse from Nuget:

- Glimpse.1.7.0
- Glimpse.Ado.1.6.0
- Glimpse.AspNet.1.5.0
- Glimpse.EF5.1.5.0
- Glimpse.WebForms.1.0.1
- EntityFramework.5.0.0

Here is my glimpse config node:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <logging level="Trace" />
    <runtimePolicies>
      <contentTypes>
        <add contentType="text/plain"/>
        <add contentType="application/json"/>
        <add contentType="text/json"/>
        <add contentType="application/xml"/>
        <add contentType="text/xml"/>
        <add contentType="application/xml"/>
      </contentTypes>
      <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet" />
      </ignoredTypes>
    </runtimePolicies>
  </glimpse>
```

Environment:

- ASP.net Web Forms
- .net 4.0
- JQuery 1.7.2

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

EDIT:
It appears if I ignore the ControlTree tab from Glimpse.WebForms add in the pages glimpse works fine with pages using web user controls:

```
<tabs>
    <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTree, Glimpse.WebForms" />
    </ignoredTypes>
</tabs>
```

Comment: Just wondering if the following sounds like your issue - https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/596

Comment: @anthonyv i did see this post. i can verify my request have the Glimpse-RequestID header assigned. So this makes me think glimpse should analyze the ajax request. correct?